# conexión local a servidor Postgres desde NExtjs version 14

Tags: nextjs, postgresql-13, cliente

estoy intentado conectarme con el proyecto de ejemplo de NEXT versión 14, dashboard no quiero utilizar la plataforma de VERCEL, deseo conectarme localmente a mi servidor local de Postgres, me sale el siguiente error:
`PS C:\Users\chesi\Documents\React\Next\proyecto-1\nextjs-dashboard> npm run seed`

> seed
> node -r dotenv/config ./scripts/seed.js

```
undefined
An error occurred while attempting to seed the database: VercelPostgresError: VercelPostgresError - 'missing_connection_string': You did not supply a 'connectionString' and no 'POSTGRES_URL' env var was found.
    at createPool (C:\Users\chesi\Documents\React\Next\proyecto-1\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\@vercel\postgres\dist\chunk-PKSWROYW.cjs:160:11)  
    at Object.get (C:\Users\chesi\Documents\React\Next\proyecto-1\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\@vercel\postgres\dist\chunk-PKSWROYW.cjs:203:16)  
    at main (C:\Users\chesi\Documents\React\Next\proyecto-1\nextjs-dashboard\scripts\seed.js:164:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\chesi\Documents\React\Next\proyecto-1\nextjs-dashboard\scripts\seed.js:174:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1378:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1437:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'missing_connection_string'
```

Por favor alguien me ayuda como seria la conexión local al servidor de postgres. en el archivo .evn.local tengo estas variables:

```
# Copy from .env.local on the Vercel dashboard
# https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/setting-up-your-database#create-a-postgres-database
NEXT_PUBLIC_POSTGRES_URL='postgresql://postgres:Holly2024@localhost:5432/nextjs-dashboard-postgres'
NEXT_PUBLIC_POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL="postgresql://postgres:Holly2024@localhost:5432/nextjs-dashboard-postgres?schema=public"
NEXT_PUBLIC_POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING="postgresql://postgres:Holly2024@localhost:5432/nextjs-dashboard-postgres?schema=public"
NEXT_PUBLIC_POSTGRES_USER="postgres"
NEXT_PUBLIC_POSTGRES_HOST="postgresql://postgres:Holly2024@localhost:5432/nextjs-dashboard-postgres?schema=public"
NEXT_PUBLIC_POSTGRES_PASSWORD="Holly2024"
NEXT_PUBLIC_POSTGRES_DATABASE="postgresql://postgres:Holly2024@localhost:5432/nextjs-dashboard-postgres?schema=public"

# `openssl rand -base64 32`
AUTH_SECRET=
AUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/api/auth
```

muchas gracias, ya me cansé llevo ocho días experimentando y no encuentro una solución, debe ser algo sencillo, espero orientación